# different 'click' callbacks in different scripts: can I control order of execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have one script that manages playlist clips.  It includes a callback that specifies what to do with the playlist when the user clicks on a clip:

```
$('div.clip').bind("click.playlist", function() {
  ...
});
```

I am now planning to add jquery-tabs, and would like to create a second script with a second callback, that specifies what to do with the tab content when the user clicks on a clip:

```
$('div.clip').bind("click.tabs", function() {
  ...
});
```

Here is my question:
When the user clicks on a clip, I want the "click.tabs" callback to execute *before* the "click.playlist" callback.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

imho i would do that in an other way:

```
$('div.clip').bind("clip.playlist", function() {
  ...
});
```

and

```
$('div.clip').bind("clip.tabs", function() {
  ...
});
```

and then fire it up with:

```
$('div.clip').click(function(){
    $(this).trigger('clip.playlist').trigger('clip.tabs');
});
```

to get the FULL control of event-chaining.

Comment: +1 This is the same as my answer, except you're triggering two custom events instead of calling the functions directly, a matter of choice. The important thing is that you cannot rely on order. If you need two things to happen in order, you do it from a single handler

Comment: your solution is 100% synchonous (which is not exactly claimed)..

my solution is asynchonous, but will fire up the first handler and directly after that the second without waiting for each other.
the difference between that and the original approach is, that the "clip.playlist"-handler will be triggered BEFORE "clip.tabs" instead of it's randomly chosen, which handler will be fired first...

synchronous-code can lead to not very responsive websites -- don't know what he want to do, but this should work as requested. - your solution is right, altough, but synchronous.

Comment: Can you point me to some place that says that jquery events are asynchronous? As far as I understand, they're not, because they're not true browser events.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620010/are-handlers-always-called-synchronously-during-jquery-click. Even in browsers, if you do fire a browser event synthetically, that event gets handled synchronously, it's a problem with IE since the event object is a global, and the nested events can really screw with you (as they have me in the past)

Comment: @JuanMendes oh! you're right (*totallyWeird*) jQuery-triggering is completely synchronous (read about that in a bug report, but this is *expected behavior*), sorry for my wrong statement!
but -- this won't change anything ;)
this solution is then exactly the same like your's, except, that you're handler-code has to be wrapped in public functions and mine in anonymous ones ;)

Answer (score 1):

The order that events handlers on the same element run is **not guaranteed**. Don't rely on it, this is true in most event systems, they are designed to be decoupled. If you really need it, you need to set a single handler that calls both functions you need in order.

Instead of

```
$('div.clip').bind("click.playlist", function() {
  doSomething();
});


$('div.clip').bind("click.tabs", function() {
  doSomethingElse();
});
```

Do

```
$('div.clip').bind("click", function() {
  doSomething();
  doSomethingElse();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you used

```
$('div.clip').click(function()
{
    func1().func2()
});
```